# SQL query that joins 3 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have just started to experiment with table relations and join queries.

I have 3 tables: `people`, `course`, `bridge`.

What I want to do is, be able to select a `student`, and get all his `course_names` which he attends, if he is a student: something like

```
SELECT(.......) where student_name = 'what I want'.
```

I'm not going to post code here, because everything I tried is a mess.

`people`:

```
people_id   student_name    
1            Alice
2            Bob
3            Caroline
4            David
5            Emma
```

`course`:

```
course_id   course_name
1           IT
2           art
3           sports
4           math
5           whatever
```

`bridge`:

```
people_id course_id people_role
1          1        student
1          3        student
1          5        student
2          1        student
2          2        student
2          5        student
4          1        teacher
```

Comment: start with code. it helps to show where you were going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT student_name, course_name
FROM people p
  INNER JOIN bridge b
    ON p.people_id = b.people_id
  INNER JOIN course c
    ON b.course_id = c.course_id
  WHERE p.student_name = 'Alice' AND b.people_role = 'student';
```

Here's an example of it running: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd5f1/2

or if you wanted a result that looked like `student_name | course1,course2,...`

```
SELECT student_name, group_concat(course_name)
FROM people p
  INNER JOIN bridge b
    ON p.people_id = b.people_id
  INNER JOIN course c
    ON b.course_id = c.course_id
  WHERE p.student_name = 'Alice' AND b.people_role = 'student'
  GROUP BY student_name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd5f1/3